# Scribe automation job to retrieving the data as excel attachment from Microsoft dynamics crm 2011 and send to customer

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, scribe-workbench

I need to run a automation job daily from scribe.

Retrieving the data from CRM as excel sheet and give the numbering to record of the excel.

The record numbers start from 1 – this will need to start each day, after the previous day.

For Example:

Day 1 – 1 ,2 ,3, 4, 5

Day 2 – 6, 7 8

Day 3 – 8, 9 .10   send it to the customer and then auto update the "status" of the records in CRM.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to help you get started: [Using Excel](https://openmind.scribesoftware.com/topics/using-excel-workbook-as-datasource)